# jQuery .inArray() always true?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to use inarray but its always returning true? Any ideas? (all li's are showing)

```
$("#select-by-color-list li").hide();

// get the select
var $dd = $('#product-variants-option-0');

if ($dd.length > 0) { // make sure we found the select we were looking for

    // save the selected value
    var selectedVal = $dd.val();

    // get the options and loop through them
    var $options = $('option', $dd);
    var arrVals = [];
    $options.each(function(){
        // push each option value and text into an array
        arrVals.push({
            val: $(this).val(),
            text: $(this).text()
        });
    });




};

//This is where it is returning true...


if($.inArray('Aqua', arrVals)) {
    $("#select-by-color-list li#aqua").show();
    };
    if($.inArray('Army', arrVals)) {
    $("#select-by-color-list li#army").show();
    };
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
if( $.inArray('Aqua', arrVals) > -1 ) {
```

or this:

```
if( $.inArray('Aqua', arrVals) !== -1 ) {
```

[The `$.inArray()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) returns the `0` based index of the item. If there's no item, it returns `-1`, which the `if()` statement will consider as `true`.

From the docs:

> Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 == false, but 0 !== false), if we're checking for the presence of value within array, we need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than) -1.

---

**EDIT:** Instead of pushing both values into the array as an object, just use one or the other, so you have an Array of strings from which you can build a multiple selector.

One way is like this:

```
  // Create an Array from the "value" or "text" of the select options
var arrVals = $.map( $dd[0].options, function( opt, i ){
    return opt.value || opt.text;
});

  // Build a multiple selector by doing a join() on the Array.
$( "#" + arrVals.join(',#') ).show();
```

If the Array looks like:

```
['Army','Aqua','Bread'];
```

The resulting selector will look like:

```
$( "#Army,#Aqua,#Bread" ).show();
```

Comment: here is the select list...<select class="single-option-selector" id="product-variants-option-0"><option value="Gunmetal Heather">Gunmetal Heather</option><option value="Kelly Green">Kelly Green</option><option value="Blackberry">Blackberry</option></select>

Comment: @Charles: This is because the `arrVals` Array doesn't contain `'Army'` or `'Aqua'`, but instead contains an object where either the `key` or `value` (not sure which) has the String you want.

Comment: How can I base an if statement on it?

Comment: @Charles: Is there some reason you need both the `val()` and `text()` as the key/value pair? Why not just one or the other? If you do that, you could actually skip the `inArray`, and just build a multiple selector that selects all elements in the Array. I'll give an example in a minute.

Comment: Thanks VERY much! I've just realised I was trying something out with that and it shouldn't be in there any longer I only need the val()... Thankg again!

Comment: Sorry if I'm taking the p**s now... What can I do about values with spaces? eg. <option value="Kelly Green">Kelly Green</option> Could I use .replace(); and replace spaces with - ?

Comment: Yes you could use `.replace()`, but instead I'd probably just have the `value` come from the server as you want it, since it isn't displayed anyway. You don't gain much by having the `text` and `value` be the same. But by allowing them to be different, you can use them for different purposes. `<option value="Kelly_Green">Kelly Green</option>`

Comment: Excellent.  So err, does anyone know why they called it "inArray" when the functionality is clearly more closely related to "indexOf"?

Answer (score 2):

ES6 to the rescue! Although not jQuery I thought worth answering for future readers...

ES6 introduces `.includes()` which works as you think `$.inArray` SHOULD work:

```js
const myArray = ["a", "b", "c"];

console.log(myArray.includes("a")) /* true */
console.log(myArray.includes("d")) /* false */
```

[Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)